# Dictionary of lists to nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following dictionary `{44: [0, 1, 0, 3, 6]}` and need to convert this to `dict1 = {44: {0:0, 1:1, 2:0, 3:3, 4:6}}` but my current for loop doesn't work:

```
maxnumbers = 5          #this is how many values are within the list
for i in list(range(maxnumbers)):
    for k in list(dict1.keys()):
        for g in dict1[k]:
            newdict[i] = g
print(num4)
```

Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = {44: [0, 1, 0, 3, 6]}
a= {i:{j:a[i][j] for i in a for j in range(len(a[i]))}}

print(a)
```

output

```
 {44: {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 3, 4: 6}}
```

Comment: This prints `{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 3, 4: 6}`

Answer (score 15):

You can use a dictionary comprehension with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
d = {44: [0, 1, 0, 3, 6]}

{k:dict(enumerate(v)) for k,v in d.items()}
# {44: {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 3, 4: 6}}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a simple nested dictionary-comprehension that uses [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
d = {44: [0, 1, 0, 3, 6]}

print({k: {i: x for i, x in enumerate(v)} for k, v in d.items()})
# {44: {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 3, 4: 6}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why your current implementation doesn't work:

```py
for i in list(range(maxnumbers)):
    for k in list(dict1.keys()):
        for g in dict1[k]:
            # this will iterate over all of the values in
            # d1[k] and the i: v pair will be overwritten by
            # the last value
            newdict[i] = g
```

Taken in steps, this would look like:

```py
# for value in [0, 1, 0, 3, 6]: Just take this set of values as an example

# first, value is 0, and say we are on i = 1, in the outer for loop
newdict[1] = 0

# Then it will progress to value = 1, but i has not changed
# which overwrites the previous value
newdict[1] = 1

# continues until that set of values is complete
```

In order to fix this, you'll want `i` and the values of `dict1[k]` to increment together. This can be accomplished with `zip`:

```py
for index, value in zip(range(maxnumbers), dict1[k]):
    newdict[index] = value
```

Also, if you need access to both the keys *and* values, use `dict.items()`:

```py
for k, values in dict1.items():
    # then you can use zip on the values
    for idx, value in zip(range(maxnumbers), values):
```

However, the `enumerate` function already facilitates this:

```py
for k, values in dict1.items():
    for idx, value in enumerate(values):
        # rest of loop
```

This is more robust, since you don't have to find what `maxnumbers` is ahead of time.

To do this in the traditional for loop that you've been using:

```py
new_dict = {}

for k, v in dict1.items():
    sub_d = {} # create a new sub_dictionary
    for i, x in enumerate(v):
        sub_d[i] = x
    # assign that new sub_d as an element in new_dict
    # when the inner for loop completes
    new_dict[k] = sub_d
```

Or, more compactly:

```py
d = {44: [0, 1, 0, 3, 6]}
new_d = {}

for k, v in d.items():
   new_d[k] = dict(enumerate(v))
```

Where the `dict` constructor will take an iterable of 2-element `tuples` as an argument, which `enumerate` provides